# Installing VS2013 while working with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I wanted to run the setup for VS2013 Pro but I am also actively working with VS2012 because it is not weekend yet! It prompted me that I should stop VS2012 before installing Vs2013 or I will need to restart later.
Restarting is fine but I can't just stop working for an hour or so until VS2013 is installed. So do you know if the installation will go fine if I am actively working, debugging in  VS2012 at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No!
At some point of installation it will automatically shut down your VS2012.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing and have experienced no issues.  I did a clean reboot (close all apps) as soon as the installation was completed, and then went back to working in VS2012.

So I can't give you a definitive answer (your mileage may vary), but based on my previous experience I have no issue doing this exact again if the need would arise.

Comment: Cool, Did you also have Team Explorer on both for version control? And does it work on both now?

Comment: I installed my add-in/tools separately after the reboot.  Both use Team Explorer with no issues.